# What is the practical use case for --net=host argument in docker?

Tags: docker, networking

For running a container we can specify `--net=host` to enable host networking, which allows the container shares the host’s networking namespace. But what is the practical use case for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found it useful in two situations:

1. You have a server process that listens on a very large number of ports, or does not use a consistent port, so the `docker run -p` option is impractical or impossible.
2. You have a process that needs to examine or manage the host network environment.  (Its wire protocol somehow depends on sending the host's IP address; it's a service-discovery system and you want it to advertise both Docker and non-Docker services running on the host.)

Host networking disables one of Docker's important isolation systems.  If you run a container with host networking, you can't use features like port remapping and you can't accept inbound connections from other containers using the container name as a host name.  In both of these cases, running the server outside Docker might be more appropriate.

In SO questions I frequently see `--net host` suggested as a hack to get around programs that have 127.0.0.1 hard-coded as the location of a database or another external resource.  This isn't usually necessary, and adding a layer of configuration (environment variables work well) and the standard Docker networking setup is better practice.

Comment: Thanks! That gave some use cases.